# Evaluating an integral over a curve

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I am having difficulty integrating $\int (y + \sin(e^{x^2})) \, dx - 2x \, dy$, over the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, traversed anti-clockwise.

I managed to do the differentiation and convert everything in terms of t, but I reach this step in the integration process, $-3\pi - \int_0^{2\pi} \sin(e^{\cos^2 t}) \sin(t) \, dt$, and then I don't know how to proceed from here. I tried integrating by parts but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I should solve this problem? Thanks so much!

Comment: That's an odd function you're trying to integrate.

Comment: The function is also periodic with period $2\pi,$ so you can integrate over *any* interval of length $2\pi,$ perhaps one that is symmetric about 0.  (In other words, you're still integrating over the circle, with the same parametrization, but with a different interval for $t$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Green's Theorem, $\int_{C}(M dx + N dy)=\iint_{R}(N_{x}-M_{y}) \;dA=\iint_R(-3) \;dA=-3A=-3\pi.$

Comment: Thanks! May I know how should we know to use Green's Theorem in this case? Is it a method of last resort in such situations if integration does not work (and assuming conditions are satisfied)?

Comment: If the line integral isn't easy to calculate directly (in particular, when the curve is composed of pieces that must be parametrized separately), then Green's Theorem is a good alternative to consider.